# Error on setting a Pooled GameObject's parent back to pooled container

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a GameObject that I am spawning from a pool, that when I try to return it to the pool I get the error:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is
>   disabled to prevent data corruption.

I have used my ObjectPooler in many projects and have never once encountered this error.

I have created simple test GameObjects and it still throws this error, using the below code.

I have a `Bomb` abstract class. I have a `PowerBomb` class that inherits from `Bomb`. `Bomb` conforms to an interface `IExplodable`.

When my player spawns a bomb, I put it as the child of the player object so the player can move around with the bomb.

My ObjectPool has the correct bomb gameobject prefab ( a PowerBomb ). and my player has the same prefab as a reference to spawn. They player also holds a reference so it knows what it is holding.

I have spent the better part of 2 days trying to figure out why my PowerBomb will not return to the object pool.

*Any help?*

**Bomb.cs**

```
public abstract class Bomb : MonoBehaviour, IExplodable {

    //Interface
    public virtual void OnDetonate() {
        Die();
    }

    public virtual void Die() {
        Debug.Log("Bomb Die()");
        ObjectPool.instance.PoolObject(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**PowerBomb.cs**

```
public class PowerBomb : Bomb {
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip sfxSpawn;
}
```

**BombManager.cs**

```
public GameObject bomb;

public void SpawnBomb(){
    GameObject obj = ObjectPool.instance.GetObject(bomb);
    if (obj == null) return;
    obj.SetActive(true);
    PlayerInstance.HoldObject(obj);
}


public void DetonateBomb(){
    bomb.GetComponent<PowerBomb>().OnDetonate();
}
```

**Player.cs**

```
[SerializeField]
private bool isHolding = false;
public bool IsHolding {
    get { return isHolding; }
    set { isHolding = value; }
}

private GameObject holdingObject;
public GameObject HoldingObject {
    get { return holdingObject; }
    set { holdingObject = value;}
}

public void HoldObject(GameObject o) {
    HoldingObject = o;
    HoldingObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
    HoldingObject.transform.position = holdingArea.transform.position;
    IsHolding = true;
}
```

**ObjectPool.cs**

```
private GameObject containerObject;
private List<GameObject>[] pooledObjects;


//Code removed for brevity. Getting from the pool is fine.    


public void PoolObject(GameObject obj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToPool.Count; i++) {
        if (objectsToPool[i].objectToPool.name.Equals(obj.name)) {
            obj.SetActive(false);

//THIS LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR
            obj.transform.SetParent(containerObject.transform); 

            pooledObjects[i].Add(obj);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `obj.transform.SetParent(containerObject.transform);`?

Comment: That keeps all my prefabs under one GameObject for tidiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't and can't modify a prefab. It might work in the Editor if you use some Editor API to modify it but it won't during run-time and it won't change the changes. You are getting this error because obj is a prefab which you are trying to modify at `obj.transform.SetParent(containerObject.transform);`.

You don't even use prefabs in a pool. That's not normal. What you do do is use the `Instantiate` function to instantiate the prefab then put the instantiated object in a pool.

```
GameObject obj =  Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

//Add instantiated Object to your pool List
pooledObjects[i].Add(obj);
```